# What is the type of this smd part?

Tags: identification, surface-mount

[image]

What is the type of this smd part?

Comment: removed the "where can I get it" part, as asking for places to purchase an item is generally off-topic here. "Q" indicates this is probably a transistor of some sort.

Comment: How have you tried to locate this SMD code?

Answer (score 2):

From the package and the layout, it looks like a transistor.

Track width hints at high current, so it's most likely a MOSFET.

[image]

G3 is the gate resistor, R5 the pulldown resistor.

The drain goes to a 3-pin inductor, who knows what that does.

You can determine if it's a NMOS or a PMOS by checking voltages on the pins. If the "S" pin is grounded, then it's a NMOS used as a low-side switch.

Answer (score 1):

That is a SOT-23-3 package, commonly used for transistors (BJT, MOSFET, etc.), voltage regulators, diodes, diode arrays, etc.

The designator `Q2` would suggest it is a transistor. The package marking `30BS` is, unfortunately, not the same as the manufacturer's part number. Finding components based on the package marking is not easy because part markings are often dynamic (changing to track binning, manufacturing dates or plants, etc.), proprietary, or absent altogether.

In order to determine what component or suitable replacement is needed here, you would need the schematic, a service manual, or bill of materials. Without those, you can determine the parameters of the component by measuring and testing it (if it is still functional) or by inferring its function from surrounding circuitry (by reverse engineering or experience).